# How to place circularImage closing button on corner of Activity

Tags: android, xml, imageview

Hi I am new to Android and i want to display a circular **cancel** button on image view for closing the dialog 
same as below image on top of the dialog.

[image: closing_circular_image]

Comment: Post your current code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply this is the code for doing the same.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/widget_icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImgeView
            android:id="@+id/filter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="7dp"
            android:background="your drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"
            android:text="Sort"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:paddingTop="-10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/yourdrwable" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your parent layout is a `RelativeLayout`, your button must have the following attributes:

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/your_margin"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/your_margin"
```